# iphone:Multitasking in iphone not possible

Tags: iphone

Does iphone support multitasking for third party applications.Canone explain me how.

Comment: Seriously? Read the book that came with your iPhone. It's been supported since iOS 4.0. Also see: http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/multitasking.html

Comment: I doesnt mean that the OS does not support multitasking(Can able to talk to some one on the phone while reading some data from the e-mail).It limits the multitasking for third party applications.It allows third party applications to save its state and does other job.when come back restore the application from where we left.But it does not allow to do the third party appln to do its job in the background.Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Depends on the app and what that "job" is. There are certain exceptions, for example, a music player can continue to play music while running in the background. Apple very clearly explains these exceptions in the documentation. Reading that will get you much further to an answer than will someone posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your device is newer than an iPhone 3G (or 1st gen iPod Touch), then yes, your application may run in the background. Note that even iOS4 doesn't allow multitasking on the older devices. What happens in iOS4 and above is that when you press the home button from an application, it switches the current app to the background - however, it is still running.

When working with games this means you have to use your application delegate to pause your game when the application is sent to the background, and (optionally) resume it when it returns, or present a "pause menu". It should also switch to a low/idle rendering loop (4FPS or similar), however, extra care has to be taken with iPad apps, which do not allow OpenGL rendering in an application that is currently in the background (in my experience). For these cases you have to completely disable the OpenGL render loop. These steps will prevent your application using unnecessary processing power while in the background.

You can see what's currently running in the background by double-tapping the home button on your device. The icons for all the apps will appear in a sliding list at the bottom of the screen. You can press and hold them to bring up the little X's allowing you to terminate the processes.

Comment: Does my application need to set a delegate to take care of it when running in background.I'm developing an application to retreive log files from other device.So my application should implement a delegate to handle that retreival if it goes to background isnt it.I'm not aware of OpenGL rendering loop.

Comment: The application delegate generated by the XCode iPhone template projects should implement (or contain, with comments) all the functions that take care of task switching between foreground and background. If you're not doing any graphics rendering (i.e. it's not a game), then you don't need to worry about OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks badgerr for helping me out to understand.

Comment: @badgerr-How does my application know that it has been put up in the swap space by the kernel and still it has to work in the background(sending and retreiving the files).How my delegate performs this function?